# Is it possible to copy a timestamp between MSQL tables?

Tags: mysql

I am creating a table for users that have been banned from my website. I want to move everything over to the new table, including the TIMESTAMP of when the record was created, but the new table will also have a TIMESTAMP for when they got banned.

When I create a row in table `foo`, I have a TIMESTAMP that registers when that row was created. I would like to transfer that row to another table (`bar`) that has a different number of columns, and keep the information from the original TIMESTAMP. How can this be done?

I am fairly new to MySQL, so correct me if I have false assumptions, but it seems that the TIMESTAMP field actually creates a TIMESTAMP when the record is created and that the existing TIMESTAMP value would have to be stored as something else like a VARCHAR in the new table. Am I off base?

**EDIT: Solved my own question**

I originally had not tried anything because I did not know *what* to try. In the end, it turns out that simply moving the value from one TIMESTAMP column to another TIMESTAMP column does, in fact, work. The only difference between the two columns is that the original TIMESTAMP has a DEFAULT of CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, whereas the new TIMESTAMP has a DEFAULT of NULL.

I used the following code:

```
INSERT INTO `bar` (`created`)
SELECT `created` FROM `foo` WHERE `user` = '000'
```

Comment: You would like to have a 'source_timestamp' column on the _`another table (bar)`_? Anything else will make tracking when the 'bar' row got created vs the source record 'interesting'? Or are you doing table replication?

Comment: I think I misunderstood what you were asking when I responded originally. I am creating a table for users that have been banned from my website. I want to move everything over to the new table, including the TIMESTAMP of when the record was created, but the new table will also have a TIMESTAMP for when they got banned.

Comment: That makes sense. Would you please add all that to your question. What you are doing is fine, We just need to know what  you want to do and how you are trying to accomplish that in code. Table definitions will help. Please add the code you have tried so far.

Comment: Sorry, I always try not to be too verbose in my questions :)